# Como adicionar localstorage em Typescript (Angular 6)

Tags: typescript, navegador-de-internet, cache, localstorage, angular-6

Tenho um código em `Typescript` (angular 6) em que eu por questões educacionais, quero saber como salvar varias variáveis mensagem com os seguintes dados no cache:

```
adicionarMensagem(preparacao: PreparacaoDeMensagem) {
    let mensagem = {
        texto: preparacao.texto,
        data: preparacao.data,
        contato: preparacao.contato,
        souEumesmo: preparacao.contato === this.emissor,
}
```

Essa é a função que uso para adicionar uma mensagem, porém quero também salvar ela no cache do browser.

Comment: Eu comentei como fazer para usar o localStorage e sessionStorage nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387053/5407

Answer (score 1):

No brower, entre outros modos de storage existe o localstorage que pode ser acessado via `window.localstorage`

Por exemplo dentro da funçåo que mostrou seria apenas chamar a função `window.localstorage.setItem(‘menssagem’, JSON.stringify(menssagem))` que seu objeto será persistido.

Espero ter ajudado