# Manter um estado da aplicação em Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu preciso manter o estado de um componente mesmo depois de navegar de uma rota para outra ou então depois de fechar a aplicação.

Eu tenho um componente onde exibe a duração de um atendimento e as informações relacionadas ao atendimento, a duração do atendimento deve estar sempre correndo mesmo depois de navegar de uma rota para a outra ou então fechar a aplicação e abrir novamente.

A duração e as informações do atendimento devem ficar mantidas até que eu finalize o atendimento.

**Como posso fazer isso em Angular?**

Comment: Creio que o melhor seria manter esse estado num serviço então

Comment: Se eu manter no serviço, quando eu fechar a aplicação e abrir novamente não terá mais os dados lá...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage` para manter os dados no navegador do usuário. Obviamente os dados só estarão disponíveis naquele navegador. A gravação e leitura é bastante simples:

```
// Armazenar item
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Ler item
localStorage.getItem('key')

// Apagar item
localStorage.removeItem('key')
```

Os dados armazenados no `localStorage`, são mantidos no navegado até que sejam apagados. Se você quiser manter os dados apenas para a sessão atual, use o `sessionStorage`:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Os métodos para ler e apagar são os mesmos do `localStorage`

Para saber mais de uma pesquisada sobre o assunto. Um link util pode ser [este](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/quando-usar-sessionstorage-e-localstorage/).

Comment: Certo, eu já tinha consciência disso porém como que irei dar continuidade na duração do meu contador mesmo quando não estiver com a aplicação aberta? Eu preciso que fique rodando em segundo plano um script que saiba o tempo decorrido mesmo após a aplicação ter sido fechada.

Comment: Guarde a data e hora inicial. Não resolve?

Comment: Acabei de pensar nisso, posso fazer uma subtração com a hora atual e continuar a contagem encima do resultado da subtração, mas isso seria uma forma ideal e correta de se fazer isso? Não teria uma forma de fazer isso usando service worker talvez?